# Snakemake on SLURM: retry attempt counter does not change

Tags: python, slurm, snakemake

I have a workflow rule with varying **time** requirements for a slurm cluster. I decorated the workflow as per [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources) to increase the slurm time limit for resubmitted jobs (my cluster `config.yaml` has the arg `restart-times: 3`), look for `resources.time`:

example_1:

```
rule run_toolx:
    ...
    resources:
        cpus=config["smk_params"]["threads"] * config["smk_params"]["thread_factor"],
        mem_mb=4000,
        time=lambda wildcards, attempt: ( 3 * ( attempt ** 2 ))
    threads:
        config["smk_params"]["threads"] * config["smk_params"]["thread_factor"]
    log:
        "logs/{sample}_toolX.log"
    shell:
        """
        echo "Queueing toolX job with a timelimit of {resources.time} minutes."
        toolX --threads {threads} | tee {log} 2> {log}
        """
```

When I review my snakemake log file for the echo, I find three job submissions with the line: "Queueing toolX job with a timelimit of 3 minutes.". I expected a time limit increase of 3, 12, 27 minutes. This is backed by the slurm logs where each submitted job requests only "00:03:00" computing time on the nodes. When the job hits this timelimit, the slurm manager interrupts it as expected:

output_1:

```
       JobID    JobName  Partition  AllocCPUS      State    Elapsed  Timelimit ExitCode 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
4983483      snakejob.+     normal          6    TIMEOUT   00:03:15   00:03:00      0:0 
4983483.bat+      batch                     6  CANCELLED   00:03:16                0:15 
4983904      snakejob.+     normal          6    TIMEOUT   00:03:03   00:03:00      0:0 
4983904.bat+      batch                     6  CANCELLED   00:03:04                0:15 
4984740      snakejob.+     normal          6    TIMEOUT   00:03:03   00:03:00      0:0 
4984740.bat+      batch                     6  CANCELLED   00:03:04                0:15
```

Apparently, either my lambda function does not work or the variable attempt is not a counter.

Thanks for sharing a thought.

**Edit_1:**

- with config["smk_params"]["threads"]=2 and config["smk_params"]["thread_factor"]=3 , so the math for `resources.cpus` works
- This [tutorial](https://github.com/nathanhaigh/snakemake-tutorial#dynamic-rule-resources) uses the same notation as my in example above.
- The `attempt` parameter was introduced with [4.1.0] - 2017-09-26. I am using snakemake 6.15.1.
- I am using the slurm job submission scripts from [Snakemake-Profiles](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm).
- some tutorials and posts use 'int(attempt)', this does not solve above problem

### Edit_2: Reproducable Example for succesful `attempt` usage

reprex_1:

```
shell.executable("bash")

localrules: all

rule all:
    input:
        "success.txt"

rule run_toolX:
    output:
        "success.txt",
    resources:
        cpus=1,
        mem_mb=100,
        time=lambda wildcards, input, threads, attempt: ( 3 * ( attempt ** 2 ))
    shell:
        """
        echo "Queueing run_quast with a timelimit of {resources.time} minutes."
        sleep 4m
        echo "Queueing run_quast with a timelimit of {resources.time} minutes." > {output}
        """
```

yielding:

output_2:

```
4985470      snakejob.+     normal          1    TIMEOUT   00:03:16   00:03:00      0:0 
4985470.bat+      batch                     1  CANCELLED   00:03:17                0:15 
4985477      snakejob.+     normal          1  COMPLETED   00:04:08   00:12:00      0:0 
4985477.bat+      batch                     1  COMPLETED   00:04:08                 0:0
```

**Experience:** I first tried it with a one-minute setup, which was working to my suprise, and then tested the exact same lambda function as in my complex rule resulting in the error. The same slurm profile was used for both examples.

It's quirky.

### Edit_3: testing all variations of the notation

my reprex **works** with or without, respectively:

- `int(attempt)`
- `int( lambda ... )`
- `lambda wildcards, input, threads, attempt: ...`
- `lambda wildcards, attempt: ...`

### Edit_4: embedding the reprex in the complex workflow

I am converging with reprex_1 to the setup/environment of the non-functional rule:

- reprex_1 **works** within complex workflow with *all* rule only pulling reprex_1 rule output
- with *all* rule only pulling *example_1* rule output and the `resources` of example_1 the counter is broken

Next culprit to test: example_1 is a *grouped rule*. Maybe rule grouping disables the `attempt` counter.

Comment: Would you be able to post a self-contained example and command-line execution that we can copy and paste to easily reproduce the issue? E.g. one without config and wildcards? Also, if you want to add information to your question, edit the question directly instead of posting comments.

Comment: I will write something up and moved my comments into the edit section of my post.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug and I have raised an issue:

[Retry counter attempt is dysfunctional for grouped rules](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1381)

That was painful.

Comment: Good detective work!  I'm curious, will it work if the non-functional example is the first rule in a group?

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that the submitted script doesn't use the `time` option appropriately. Can you check your profile script's `cluster` option?

This is an incomplete string, but the key idea is to show that the time option should reference the appropriate option in `resources`:

```yaml
cluster: "sbatch --parsable -t {resources.time}"
```

As a debugging experiment, you could also try starting with a specific attempt number:

```sh
snakemake -s Snakefile -j 1 --attempt 3 -n
```

If this doesn't modify the submission characteristics, then there is a problem with `snakemake` handling of attempt (as opposed to a problem during job submission to SLURM).

Comment: An interesting approach, but my complex rule and the reprex make use of the same cluster config and job submission scripts in their [slurm profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm). For latter, the `sacct` output shows the correct increase of the counter (see column _Timelimit_ in the code boxes above), hence I do not assume the error in the cluster config.